# Django ManyToMany field object automatically pre-fills

Tags: python, django

[image: There should only be one item and quantity listed]I have an PaypalOrder model that is created when someone orders from a website, and it has a ManyToManyField that connects it to multiple OrderItems. Whenever I create a PaypalOrder, it automatically lists every OrderItem that exists in the django admin panel. How do I only list the objects that I set it to connect to?

my models.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    is_a_subscription = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey('Subscription', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class PaypalOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    items_and_quantities = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, blank=True, related_name="paypalorder")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

my view:

```
order = PaypalOrder.objects.create(
                user = user,
                full_name= resp['subscriber']['name']['given_name'] + " " + resp['subscriber']['name']['surname'],
                email = resp['subscriber']['email_address'],
                city = resp['subscriber']['shipping_address']['address']['admin_area_2'],
                state = resp['subscriber']['shipping_address']['address']['admin_area_1'],
                address1 = resp['subscriber']['shipping_address']['address']['address_line_1'],
                address2 = addr2,
                zipcode = resp['subscriber']['shipping_address']['address']['postal_code'],
                country_code = resp['subscriber']['shipping_address']['address']['country_code'],
                total_paid = resp['billing_info']['last_payment']['amount']['value'],
                order_id = "product_ID: " + resp['id'],
                subscription_id = resp['plan_id'],
                created_at = resp['create_time'],
            )
            order.save()
            subscription = Subscription.objects.create(user = request.user, paypal_order = order)

order.items_and_quantities.set(OrderItem.objects.filter(pk=100))
```

Comment: Hello, did you manage to figure out what was going on? I have the same issue as you where if i declare a many to many field, the django admin automatically shows the field is automatically populated with every object from the other model

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are being tricked by the Front end; look again; even when the Django admin displays all the items, only those related to PayPal orders are highlighted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).